# jQuery UI dialog with iframe and anchors

Tags: jquery, user-interface, iframe, dialog, anchor

I am loading a page into an iFrame in the dialog.
This is a help page with anchor tags. When I load the page using an anchor or even when using the anchor tags in the dialog the browser jumps up to the anchor, even if the dialog is centred.

See: http://immoshots.com/test/jquery.ui.dialog/default.html

Is there a workaround for this?

Another question is why I have double scrollbars.

And btw what's up with the G_JS_API in the top of the iFrame?

Comment: I have an identical issue to this and unfortunately, you've deleted the test page. Do you perchance have a copy of this that you could put on jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the inline style for the height on `id="divId"` and the outside set of scrollbars goes away.

For the G_JS_API you have something outputting the string before the JS is added to the element `"
        G_JS_API

        "`

A stray output somewhere?

Are you using a browser that you can easily inspect elements?  In Chrome or Firefox just right click on something, click on inspect element.  From there you can see what styles are affecting the divs and where text is coming from

Comment: Yup, you need to use a tool for inspect elements, I have just browsed your url with the FireBug (Mozilla) and I could see the problems that you have on styles. You can use FireBug in almost any browser. FireBug: http://getfirebug.com/

Comment: OK, I'll try that.. what about the anchors?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what 'Remove the inline style for the height on id="divId"' means..

Comment: There is a style on the Div with the ID of "divId".  inside of that style there is a height set to 493 px.  If you take the height style off of the div, the outside scrollbars go away.